Fedora 39 - Installing mysql workbench
I'm having some troubles installing mysql workbench on Fedora 39. I'm following https://idroot.us/install-mysql-workbench-fedora-37.
> sudo dnf install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-fc39-2.noarch.rpm

Last metadata expiration check: 0:11:31 ago on Thu 25 Apr 2024 06:33:11 AM CEST.
mysql80-community-release-fc39-2.noarch.rpm      13 kB/s |  10 kB     00:00    
Package mysql80-community-release-fc39-2.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

> sudo rpm -Uvh mysql80-community-release-*

warning: mysql80-community-release-fc39-1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3a79bd29: NOKEY
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    package mysql80-community-release-fc39-2.noarch (which is newer than mysql80-community-release-fc39-1.noarch) is already installed

> sudo dnf install mysql-workbench-community

Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:06 ago on Thu 25 Apr 2024 06:33:11 AM CEST.
No match for argument: mysql-workbench-community
Error: Unable to find a match: mysql-workbench-community

Why can't it find the package?

I haven't tried it, but sudo dnf install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-fc39-1.noarch.rpm might work (note the version number 1 instead of 2).

See https://computingforgeeks.com/install-and-use-mysql-workbench-on-fedora/.

Ok, so I was able to install it following the link in @ksyrium's comment. I had to follow the snap installation process though:
sudo dnf install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo dnf install snapd fuse squashfuse kernel-modules -y
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
sudo reboot
sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community

Also after rebooting (sudo reboot), when running the last command I got
error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged

I'm not sure how I got past that honestly, I looked at:
> systemctl status snapd.socket

● snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-04-25 13:07:52 CEST; 22min ago
   Triggers: ● snapd.service
     Listen: /run/snapd.socket (Stream)
             /run/snapd-snap.socket (Stream)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 76794)
     Memory: 0B
        CPU: 234us
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.socket

> systemctl status snapd.service

● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-04-25 13:08:30 CEST; 22min ago
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
   Main PID: 4335 (snapd)
      Tasks: 23 (limit: 76794)
     Memory: 33.7M
        CPU: 534ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
             └─4335 /usr/libexec/snapd/snapd

> systemctl status snapd.seeded.service

○ snapd.seeded.service - Wait until snapd is fully seeded
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)

And I think I tried to star the last manually, but it didn't fix it, so I shut it down again and somehow by that time I was able to install mysql-workbench. Go figure
